How to add form elements to Dialog in Dojo dynamically
Please give me a code example on how to dynamically add any form elements to Dialog.
var myDialog = new Dialog({
    title: "Edit form",
    style: "width: 300px; height: 200px"
});
myDialog.show();

It seems I figured it out a little, but I need to somehow wrap the elements in a div since they go in the Dialog box in one line, I don’t know how to do this
var form = new Form();

var myDialog = new Dialog({
    content: form,
    title: "Dialog Box",
    style: "width: 300px; height: 200px"
});

new Select({
    name: "select2",
    options: [
        { label: "Item1", value: "1" },
        { label: "Item2", value: "2" },
        { label: "Item3", value: "3" }
    ]
}).placeAt(form.containerNode);

